# SQL Select Distinct based on Conditional

Tags: sql, sql-server

Assumptions:
ITEM STATUS in STAGINGLINE:  0 - NOT STARTED, 1 - VERIFIED, 2 - MISCOUNT

Want only one line to show per ASN so easiest way is using DISTINCT....

```
SELECT DISTINCT ASN, STATUS 
FROM STAGINGLINE
```

However, I can't use a simple distinct because of the multiple STATUS possibilities, you would get multiples for each status.

Result set should show only 2 “ASNs”: 123 and 343

Example STAGINGLINE Table

### Case 1:

```
(ASN #, ITEM #, STATUS, QTY ,ACTUAL)
123   898      0       4      NULL
123   344      0       9      NULL
123   123      0       2      NULL
123   534      0       1      NULL
343   111      1       6      6
```

ResultSet needs to be:

```
123  NOT STARTED (because all 0)
343  VERIFIED
```

### Case 2:

```
(ASN #, ITEM #, STATUS, QTY ,ACTUAL)
123   898      1       4      4
123   344      0       9      NULL
123   123      0       2      NULL
123   534      0       1      NULL
```

ResultSet needs to be:

```
123  IN PROGRESS (because at least one of them is not in a 0 STATUS)
343  VERIFIED
```

### Case 3:

```
(ASN #, ITEM #, STATUS, QTY ,ACTUAL)
123   898      1       4      4
123   344      2       9      5  <- MISCOUNT
123   123      0       2      NULL
123   534      0       1      NULL
```

ResultSet needs to be:

```
123  MISCOUNT (because of the existence of a 2 in at least one of the STATUS column)
343  VERIFIED
```

### Case 4:

```
(ASN #, ITEM #, STATUS, QTY ,ACTUAL)
123   898      1       4      4
123   344      1       9      9
123   123      1       2      2
123   534      1       1      1
```

ResultSet needs to be:

```
123  VERIFIED (because all are STATUS of 1)
343  VERIFIED
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can you try this,

```
SELECT ASN, 
        CASE WHEN MAX_STATUS = 2 THEN 'MISCOUNT'
             WHEN MAX_STATUS = 0 THEN 'NOT STARTED'
             WHEN MAX_STATUS = 1 AND MIN_STATUS = 1 THEN 'VERIFIED'
             WHEN MAX_STATUS = 1 AND MIN_STATUS = 0 THEN 'IN-PROGRESS'
         END STATUS
FROM         
(SELECT ASN, MAX(STATUS) MAX_STATUS, MIN(STATS) MIN_STATUS
FROM STAGELINE
GROUP BY ASN) A
```

Answer (score 3):

Are you looking for `max()`:

```
select asn, max(status)
from t
group by asn;
```

Or perhaps `max()` with `case`:

```
select (case max(status) when 0 then 'NOT STARTED'
                         when 1 then 'VERIFIED'
                         when 2 then 'MISCOUNT'
        end)
from t
group by asn;
```

EDIT:

The rules seem a bit more detailed:

```
select (case when max(status) = 0 then 'NOT STARTED'
             when max(status) = 1 and min(status) = max(status) then 'VERIFIED'
             when max(status) = 2 then 'MISCOUNT'
             else 'IN PROGRESS'
        end)
from t
group by asn;
```